# How to concatenate Ruby conditions dynamically with &&?

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to concatenate conditions dynamically with an `&&` operator?

I've got this:

```
def condition(name)
  if Profile.reflect_on_association(name)
    send(name).present? && send(name).persisted?
  else
    send(name).present?
  end
end
```

I tried to build the conditions inside an array and then join them with `&&` but that didn't work of course.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: "but that didn't work of course" - didn't work __how__? What did you do, what did you expect to happen, what happened instead?

Comment: Hint: you can always dynamically do _anything_ in ruby with `eval` 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit unclear on the wording of your original question -- are you looking for a way to combine `send(name).present? && send(name).persisted?`?

One option is this: `%i[present? persisted?].all? { |condition| send(name).send(condition) }`

Though if you only have a few enumerated conditions, I think the metaprogramming is worse for readability and your code as written in the original question is probably better.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if what you call your "conditions" is an array of values or function resulting in truthy/fasly values, you can actually evaluate them directly with all?:

```
conditions_1 = [1, 2, nil]
conditions_1.all? # => false

conditions_2 = [1, true, "lala"]
conditions_2.all? # => true
```

'all?' evaluates if all the items in the array respect a condition - without params it will just evaluate if they are all true. While not exactly what you asked for but it should lead to the same result.

Comment: "but it should lead to the same result" - I have one word for you: short-circuiting.

Comment: That is, code like `if user && user.name`. You can't simply put them into an array and call `.all?` on it.